# Two cities sharing resource square in Civ2

Tags: civilization-2

I have two cities sharing a resource square in Civilization 2. It seems like it's a bug. Now, I don't want to unclick it because, well, it's on a wheat between the two cities, and you can't go wrong with a shared wheat!!

Has anyone run into this before? If so, under what conditions were you able to reproduce it?

Screenshots below. The shared wheat is the one between Rome and Antium. I had JUST built Antium and was noting it would have one overlapping tile with Rome, but that's okay, as it still had 19 others. But then I noticed it took the wheat. So I went into Rome thinking "Why doesn't Rome have its wheat taken? I know there's other bonus resources around, but it should pick the wheat by size 9!" Go in and sure enough it has the wheat already. A true wtf moment.

[image: The map][image: Notice the wheat on the left][image: Notice the wheat on the right]

Comment: Good question.  I know this doesn't happen in the Test of Time version.

Comment: What version of Civilization II are you playing? The original one, the Multiplayer Gold Edition, or perhaps another one? Maybe this bug has been solved in one of the patches or later versions of the game.

Comment: So much nostalgia brought up by this post. Civ V is awesome, but this one's a classic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "bug" happened to me a couple of times, let's say I've created a city, then I started to explore. If you find a village next to your city when you enter this village there's a chance you will create a new city and then this "bug" happens.

Comment: Interesting - this was indeed the first tile of the city.